# Can I bundle all java classes in to jar app?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have created a project to collect the daily status in an xls sheet, using the selenium webdriver.

Currently it runs well.

Can I make this project into a standalone application or a executable jar?  Or is there some other way to collect the status by clicking on the application or jar to open it without having to compile and run from eclipse?

Comment: Do you use Maven or just Eclipse? If it is a Maven project, take a look at /questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven

Comment: use export jar option in eclipse. 
http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-33.htm

Comment: i have created as jar.. But how to execute this jar?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From Eclipse select Export -> Runnable JAR File

Select 'Extract required libraries into generated JAR'

When you have your JAR file execute :

> java -jar MyJar.jar

Answer (score 0):

You can use install4j from below mention URL. It will make executable jar and application.exe also you can make installer for different platforms such as Mac, Windows and Linux.

https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html

hope it will help